# How can I make a query that will sort data on two criteria then add all values corresponding to that criteria from the initial table/query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access Database with a query, called Billing Hours which contains the following fields: Project Name, Customer, Employee, Date Worked, Work Description, Billable Hours and Non-billable Hours.

What this query does is show on each row the date on which an employee worked, what customer he worked for, what project, what he did, how many hours were billable and how many were non-billable.

I want to make a new query, based on this that will sum up total Billable Hours and Non-billable Hours spent by each Employee on each Project Name, and I can't seem to find a way to do that.

I have managed to make queries that will extract total number of hours per project and total number of hours per employee, but as a whole, not per project AND per employee.

I have tried using DISTINCT, UNION, sorting, joining on, joining left, right and center, nothing seems to work.

Furthermore what really doesn't help is that it's been probably 18 years since I last worked in SQL, and the first time I'm dealing with Access, this is sort of something I'm trying to help someone out with and it's frustrating.

The result would look something like

---

Employee_Name_1 Project_Name_1 Number_of_BH1 Number_of_NBH1

Employee_Name_1 Project_Name_2 Number_of_BH2 Number_of_NBH2

Employee_Name_2 Project_Name_1 Number_of_BH3 Number_of_NBH3

and so on

---

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would help a lot. I'm guessing it's not even that hard. If I can provide any further information, please let me know.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use sum and group  by

```
select  Project_Name, Employee, sum( Billable_Hours), sum( Npn_Billable_Hours)
from my_table  
group by  Project_Name, Employee
```

for a date range  you need

select  Project_Name, Employee, sum( Billable_Hours), sum( Npn_Billable_Hours)
    from my_table
    WHERE Date_Worked Between my_start_date And my_end_date 
    group by  Project_Name, Employee

Comment: I now feel stupid. Mostly because I've done this at some point today, but for some reason felt unsatisfied with the outcome and just moved on. But that was, in fact, the outcome I was looking for. So I now feel stupid. So thanks for that. Oh, and thank you for sorting me out, too! :)

Comment: No, wait, I know why that was not it, sorry for not phrasing the initial question completely.

The thing is I want to pull a report on total work hours per employee per project corresponding to a certain date range that I can input. So for example I want to know for Project 1, between X and Y, how many hours Employee 1, 2 and 3 spent on the task. 

When I add the date criteria, I no longer get a list like 
Project1 Employee1 Total Hours, but instead I get
Project1 Employee1 Hours_Day1
Project1 Employee1 Hours_Day2 ...instead of

Project1 Employee1 TotalHRSinDateRange.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: I managed to add them up in the report. But am still curious as to how I would make the query work.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick! I'm assuming it was a basic thing, but... heh. Thank you!!